# WP-CLI Write Serialized string to database plugin options

Tags: wordpress, command-line

I'm trying to install and activate Wordpress plugin via WP-CLI tool, but on install - the plugin doesn't populate `wp_options` table with PHP serialized string.

How can I manually do that (I have the serialized string that I should use) via console, I'm thinking about `wp db query` command?